# version_id shows as null in network tab payload when creating a verse

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Whenever I try to create a new verse, version_id appears as null in the payload under the network tab in dev tools, and this error also appears: POST http://localhost:8000/verses 500 (Internal Server Error). But when I console warn it it shows the correct information.

VerseForm

```
const initialState = {
  verse: '',
  content: '',
  version_id: {
    id: 0,
    label: '',
  },
};
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.warn('currentVerse.version_id:', currentVerse.version_id);
    if (verseObj.id) {
      updateVerse(user, currentVerse, verseObj.id)
        .then(() => router.push('/'));
    } else {
      const payload = { ...currentVerse };
      createVerse(payload, user).then(setCurrentVerse(initialState))
        .then(() => router.push('/'));
    }
  };

  return (
    <Form className="form-floating" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <h2 className="text-black mt-5">{verseObj.id ? 'Update' : 'Create'} a Verse</h2>
      <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingInput1" label="Book, Chapter & Verse" 
        className="mb-3">
        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Book, Chapter & Verse" name="verse" 
         value={currentVerse.verse} onChange={handleChange} required />
      </FloatingLabel>
      <FloatingLabel controlId="floatingInput1" label="Content" className="mb-3">
        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Content" name="content" value= 
         {currentVerse.content} onChange={handleChange} required />
      </FloatingLabel>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3">
        <Form.Select onChange={handleChange} className="mb-3" name="version_id" value= 
         {currentVerse.version_id.id} required>
          <option value="">Select a Version</option>
          {versions.map((version) => (
            <option key={version.id} value={version.id}>
              {version.label}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Form.Select>
      </Form.Group>
      <Button type="submit" disabled={!currentVerse.version_id}>
        {verseObj.id ? 'Update' : 'Create'} Verse
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}

VerseForm.propTypes = {
  verseObj: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    verse: PropTypes.string,
    content: PropTypes.string,
    version_id: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number,
      label: PropTypes.string,
    }),
  }),
  user: PropTypes.shape({
    uid: PropTypes.string,
    id: PropTypes.number,
  }).isRequired,
};

VerseForm.defaultProps = {
  verseObj: initialState,
};
```

I've tried getting help with this elsewhere, but it's hard on a Saturday.

Edit: Verse view:

```
def create(self, request):
    """Handle POST requests for a single post"""
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.data["uid"])
    version = Version.objects.get(id=request.data["version_id"])
    verse = Verse.objects.create(
        verse = request.data["verse"],
        content = request.data["content"],
        uid = user,
        version_id = version
        )
    serializer = VerseSerializer(verse)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Verse model:

```
class Verse(models.Model):
uid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
version_id = models.ForeignKey(Version, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
verse = models.TextField(max_length=100)
content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
```

Version model:

```
class Version(models.Model):
label = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Can we see the backend code?